# Angular 2 Pipe From Filtered JSON

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm going to use pipe to filter some json and show Name based on value

this is my JSON

```html
  bankAccountUsage = [
    { value: 1, name: "x" },
    { value: 2, name: "y" },
    { value: 3, name: "z" }
  ];
```

this is the PIPE :

```html
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { StaticValuesService } from '../../services/static-values.service';
import { } from '../../services/static-values.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'accountUsageType'
})
export class AccountUsageTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private Accounusages;
  transform(value: number, args?: any): any {
       this.Accounusages.filter(val => {
         if (val.value === value) {
        console.log(val);
         return val.name;
      }
     

    });
  }
 
  constructor(private _statcvalues: StaticValuesService) {
    this.Accounusages = this._statcvalues.bankAccountUsage;
    
  }

}
```

this is the result of Console.log(val)

```
Object {value: 1, name: "x"}
```

HTML :

```html
       <td>{{account.AccountType | accountUsageType}}</td>
```

But result is Empty

thanks

Comment: if I put return there this is what I get `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing the `return` *statement*;
2. Your `value` is a primitive `variable`, so, the pipe **must** return, of course, a single `variable`. You could use the [**`Array#find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, as below:

```
return this.Accounusages.find(val => val.value === value);
```

Comment: if I put return there this is what I get [object Object]

Comment: this is the Json `{value: 1, name: "x"}` so I believe val.name is correct

Comment: this works `return this.Accounusages.find(val => val.value === value).name`

thanks

Comment: Just make sure the find returns something different that `undefined`, or you'll get an exception...